# You might think you don't need me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This riddle might be a little easier to solve, but I hope you enjoy the rhymes.

> You might think you don't need me, that you can go without, 
> but I
>   will come lurking, there will be no doubt.
>
> You may try to get rid of me, you ignorant fool! 
> I can bear gifts, I'm a powerful tool.
>
> You might not expect me, You might try to ignore,
>   
> But my power over you, it cannot be tore.
>
> You can try and put up a valiant fight, 
> But I always succeed, you
>   strengthen my might!
>
> You can hide in the shadows, and creep in the night. 
> But I will
>   find you, and show you my smite!
>
> Some can't get enough, of what I can give,
>   
>  Some struggle without, from the life that they live.

---

*If you enjoyed this riddle, some of my other rhyming riddles can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brhyme%5D%20user%3A11244%20is%3Aquestion)*.

Comment: Very nice rhymes.

Comment: @MarkN I sense some sort of addiction here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is it:

> Sleep?

You might think you don't need me, that you can go without, 
but I will come lurking, there will be no doubt.

> People can try to stay awake / avoid sleep but it'll always win out.

You may try to get rid of me, you ignorant fool! 
I can bear gifts, I'm a powerful tool.

> People can drink coffee etc to stay awake but it's a powerful tool in that it heals and rejuvenates the mind.

You might not expect me, You might try to ignore,
 
But my power over you, it cannot be tore.

> You can fall asleep when least expecting it - hopefully not while driving any heavy machinery..

You can try and put up a valiant fight, 
But I always succeed, you strengthen my might!

> The longer you go without sleeping the stronger the urge!

You can hide in the shadows, and creep in the night. 
But I will find you, and show you my smite!

> Reference to sleeping in the dark / at night.

Some can't get enough, of what I can give, 
Some struggle without, from the life that they live.

> Some people love sleeping and can't get enough of it. Some people lead lives too busy to get much of it.

Comment: I was going to say this as well - but you put it much more eloquently than I have the energy to do right now :)

Comment: +1 I like the question, and I like the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> Money

You might think you don't need me, that you can go without,
but I will come lurking, there will be no doubt.

> Everyone needs money, even though some try to escape it. You need money to "run away", and bills will always come.

You may try to get rid of me, you ignorant fool!
I can bear gifts, I'm a powerful tool.

> Some try to spend their money to get rid of it. Money also buys almost anything, and can be a tool to accomplish much.

You might not expect me, You might try to ignore,
But my power over you, it cannot be tore.

> Little strained here... One might try to ignore money (money problems), but we are all subject to the power of money.

You can try and put up a valiant fight,
But I always succeed, you strengthen my might!

> Fighting against the influence of money can sometimes increase the amount of money (bribery).

You can hide in the shadows, and creep in the night.
But I will find you, and show you my smite!

> Theives hide in the shadows to steal money, but money can buy security systems to catch them.

Some can't get enough, of what I can give,
Some struggle without, from the life that they live.

> Some are always trying to get more money, then the poor can't get enough money to live their lives.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's

> TIME.

*You might think you don't need me, that you can go without,*

> Some people try to get too much done in way too little time.

*but I will come lurking, there will be no doubt.*

> Time is always ticking away.

*You may try to get rid of me, you ignorant fool!*

> You can kill time, waste time, etc.

*I can bear gifts, I'm a powerful tool.*

> With enough time, you can do almost anything.

*You might not expect me, You might try to ignore,*

> If you don't want to be too stressed, you might try to ignore the ticking clock.

*But my power over you, it cannot be tore.*

> Same as the second line.

*You can try and put up a valiant fight,

But I always succeed, you strengthen my might!*

> Working against the clock only makes the time race by faster.

*You can hide in the shadows, and creep in the night.

But I will find you, and show you my smite!*

> "Smite" is an anagram of "times". Your time is always ticking away, no matter where you hide.

*Some can't get enough, of what I can give,*

> There's not enough time to do everything I want to!

*Some struggle without, from the life that they live.*

> You can still struggle on in life with no spare time.

Comment: This was my thought to but you beat me too it

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> ageing.

You might think you don't need me, that you can go without, 
but I will come lurking, there will be no doubt.

> Most dont like aging, and rather dont.

You may try to get rid of me, you ignorant fool! 
I can bear gifts, I'm a powerful tool.

> Some use botox to hide it.

You might not expect me, You might try to ignore, 
But my power over you, it cannot be tore.

> Most dont want to admit they get older.

You can try and put up a valiant fight, 
But I always succeed, you strengthen my might!

> You can use botox but it's impossible to keep hiding that your aging.

You can hide in the shadows, and creep in the night. 
But I will find you, and show you my smite!

> your sking ages faster in the sun, you can hide in the dark but eventualy your skin will age.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with:

> Wisdom

You might think you don't need me, that you can go without,

> Foolish people think they don't need wisdom.

but I will come lurking, there will be no doubt.

> Others will try to give you wisdom to people who do foolish things.

You may try to get rid of me, you ignorant fool!

> Fool! :) Also, foolish people try to ignore the words of the wise.

I can bear gifts, I'm a powerful tool.

> Its' good to have wisdom to keep you out of trouble.

You might not expect me, You might try to ignore,

> Wisdom can come from unexpected places.

But my power over you, it cannot be tore.

> Time tested wisdom wins out over foolish pursuits.

You can try and put up a valiant fight,

> Again, ignoring the words of the wise.

But I always succeed, you strengthen my might!

> Again, time tested wisdom wins over foolish pursuits.

You can hide in the shadows, and creep in the night.

> Again, ignoring the words of the wise.

But I will find you, and show you my smite!

> Again, time tested wisdom wins over foolish pursuits.

Some can't get enough, of what I can give,

> Some people love learning and gaining wisdom.

Some struggle without, from the life that they live.

> Foolishness can get a person into all kinds of trouble.